# Issues extracting shell archive (broken pipes)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

A little background first:

I recently started working on updating Sven-Ola's [DebianKit](https://sven-ola.commando.de/repo/debian-kit-en.html) project and after successfully (I hope), changing it to my needs and fixing compatibility issues, I've run into some trouble creating the archive itself.

My experience with `sharutils` is somewhat limited and StackOverflow seems to lack material in this department as well. If you download the original shell archive, `debian-kit-1-6-testing.shar`, it'll have a directory structure similar to this in 7z:

```
debian-kit-1-6-testing.shar
|--debian-kit-1-6-testing
|   |--.
|      |--armel
|      |--devel
|      |--i386
|      |--...
```

Meanwhile, the archive I create can't be opened in 7z and throws `sed: short write: broken pipe` when I try to extract it using `sh`.

I've tried using `shar kit > kit.shar` with `-z` but that doesn't help either.